# Не могли бы вы мне помочь со способом нахождения самого длинного слова с списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот код, который находит в строке все слова и заносит их в список, а потом печатает эти слова в столбец, как найти самое длинное из этих слов?

```
list = str(input()).split()

for i in list:
 print(i)

print("") 
print(list)
```

Comment: Самое длинное слово может быть одно или несколько?

Comment: Допустим можно и одно.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию `max`, и всё получается просто в 1 строку:

```
list = str(input()).split()
print(max(list, key=len))
```

[Документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)

[Рабочий пример](https://repl.it/I2zK/1)

Comment: Для 3 питона: print(max(input().split(), key=len))

Comment: Да точно, не заметил метку python3

Comment: К сожалению не работает)

Comment: @Михаил Проверил только что ещё раз и всё работает, добавил в ответ рабочий пример

Answer (score 2):

##### Или так:

```
sentense = "какое-либо предложение"
words = dict()
for word in sentense.split(" "):
  words[len(word)] = word

biggest_word = words[max(words)]
print(biggest_word)
```

Comment: Я изменил имя `biggestWord` на `biggest_word`, чтобы оно было в соответствии с [PEP 8 - руководством по написанию кода на Python](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#section-22) - lower_case_with_underscores (слова из маленьких букв с подчеркиваниями). Красивое решение, между прочим.

Comment: @MarianD, некрасивое, расточительное, многословное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать lambda-функцию, то примет следующий вид:

```
print (lambda list: (max(list, key=len)))(str(input()).split())
```

Еще вариант на коленке через сортировку:

```
print sorted(str(input()).split())[-1]
```

Comment: Самовызывающая лямбда с одним использованием параметра напоминает мне `(... == True) == True`

Comment: Сортировка не работает.

Answer (score -2):

```
b1 =  " " +  input()   + " "
k= 0
k1= 0
a = "ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮЪйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЁё"
m = 0
x123  = 0
c = 0
x = 0
x12345676 = 0
o = 0
cs = []
cs1 = []
for x123 in range(x123, len(b1)):
    x12345676 = 0
    if  b1[x123]== " ":
        x123 = x123 + 0
    for x in range(x123 , len(b1)):

        if  b1[x]== " ":
            break
        x12345676 =         x12345676 +  1
    if  m > c :
        m = m
        cs1 = cs1
    else:
        m = c
        cs1 = cs
    for x1 in range(0, len(a)):
        if b1[x123-1] == " " and b1[x123] == a[x1]:
            o = o + 1
            k+=1
            c = 0
            cs = []
            for x1234567 in range(x123  ,x123 + x12345676+1):
                for x1s in range(0, len(a)):
                    if b1[x1234567] == a[x1s]:
                        c += 1
                        cs += [a[x1s]]
print(m, cs1)
```

если в лоб идти и так решать чуток доработал, добавил "Её". если учитель информатики, запретит использовать, что не проходили.

Comment: что это вообще? О_О

Comment: @ZxNuClear, это медленный код, который работает если в строке только русские буквы без Ёё и пробелы.

Comment: ну там    дополнить нечего    осталось