# Номер первого самого длинного слова

Tags: python

> Дан произвольный текст. Найдите номер первого самого длинного слова в нем.

Пересмотрел форум, пересмотрел [стр1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1048569/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5), [стр2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674205/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5) эти страницы , но они мне не помогли решить мою задачу

Comment: Задача очень сильно осложняется, если в тексте есть спец. символы и знаки препинания. Это относится к Вашему вопросу? Например, без лексического анализатора сложно будет распарсить такой текст: `It's John's ball, isn't it?`.

Comment: @nomnoms12: Нет. Мне достаточно разобраться с самым простым текстом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом:

1. Составить список слов, разделив текст по пробелам (`split`)
2. Найти максимальный элемент, используя функцию `max` и, в качестве ключа к ней, функцию, возвращающую длину элемента (`len`)
3. Найти индекс полученного слова в списке (`index`) и прибавить к нему `1`, так как нумерация начинается с `0`

***Пример:***

```py
def main():
    text = 'Дан произвольный текст Найдите номер первого самого длинного слова в нем'

    words = text.split()
    max_word = max(words, key=len)
    print(words.index(max_word) + 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
2
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), чтобы получить индекс нужного элемента за один вызов `max(...)`. Кроме этого можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями, чтобы не учитывать символы пунктуации при расчете длины слов.

```
text = "Дан произвольный текст. Найдите номер первого самого длинного слова в нем."

res = max(enumerate(re.findall(r"\b(\w+)\b", text), 1), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))[0]
```

результат:

```
In [20]: res
Out[20]: 2
```

---

пошагово:

```
In [25]: re.findall(r"\b(\w+)\b", text)
Out[25]:
['Дан',
 'произвольный',
 'текст',
 'Найдите',
 'номер',
 'первого',
 'самого',
 'длинного',
 'слова',
 'в',
 'нем']

In [26]: list(enumerate(re.findall(r"\b(\w+)\b", text), 1))
Out[26]:
[(1, 'Дан'),
 (2, 'произвольный'),
 (3, 'текст'),
 (4, 'Найдите'),
 (5, 'номер'),
 (6, 'первого'),
 (7, 'самого'),
 (8, 'длинного'),
 (9, 'слова'),
 (10, 'в'),
 (11, 'нем')]

In [27]: max(enumerate(re.findall(r"\b(\w+)\b", text), 1), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))
Out[27]: (2, 'произвольный')
```

Comment: Выглядит довольно монструозно

Comment: @ArtyomLazovikov, согласен, немного "тяжеловато" выглядит. Ничего не могу с собой поделать - Pandas привил мне любовь к однострочным решениям)